# Pulling Custom Binding from arbitrary config file

Tags: c#, wcf

I am connecting to a web service that requires a custom binding. I have it working, but the issue is I am not able to leave the custom binding in the *app.config*. I put another **.config* file in the project and I am trying to read from it. I'm able to find the binding I want, but it comes out as a BindingElement. Any idea of how to convert this to a regular binding?

```
        string assemblyPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase), @"my.config");

        assemblyPath = assemblyPath.Replace(@"file:\", "");

        ExeConfigurationFileMap exeConfigurationFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
        exeConfigurationFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = assemblyPath;

        Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(exeConfigurationFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

        ServiceModelSectionGroup serviceModelSectionGroup = ServiceModelSectionGroup.GetSectionGroup(configuration);

        var BindingsSection = serviceModelSectionGroup.Bindings;

        //Console.WriteLine(temp.Name);
        //Console.WriteLine(temp.GetType());

        //does not pull from the loaded config, but if i stick it in the app regular config it works
        var binding = new CustomBinding("MyCustomBinding");




        var endPoint = CreateEndPointAddress(new X509Certificate2(GetCertificate(thumbprint)), url);
        var client = new MyWebService(binding, endPoint);
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

Can you transform the custom binding to a regular binding, apply it in the regular configuration file? it appears to be that you have transformed it properly and the main issue is how to read it on the client-side from another configuration file.
Here is an example of how to read the configuration from another configuration.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/configuration-channel-factory
There are some points we should pay utmost attention to in this example (the same applies to your current situation).

1. We should ensure that the project could find another configuration
   properly. Generally, we do the below changes.
   [image]
2. The endpoint name and endpoint address should correspond to the configuration file.

```
    ConfigurationChannelFactory factory1 = new 
    ConfigurationChannelFactory("BasicHttpBinding_IService1", newConfiguration, 
    new EndpointAddress("http://10.157.13.70:8080"));
```

---

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ITestService" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
       <!--pay attention to the Contract property. it should be in the client-side.-->
      <endpoint address="http://10.157.13.70:8080/" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="SimpleTest.IService1"
          name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
      <endpoint address="http://10.157.13.69:4386/" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ITestService" contract="SimpleTest.ITestService"
          name="BasicHttpBinding_ITestService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: okay, excuse my ignorance as I am very new to web services. Creating that custom channel makes sense, but I am unsure how I would use the channel with my proxy class. The constructor that my webservice uses calls for a binding and an endpoint. Is the binding and channel almost the same thing?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Em, almost, the client proxy is also implemented by the creation of the communication channel. The shape of the WCF channel consists of binding and endpoint address.
Calling services through proxy classes and invoking services through channel factory is one thing.